# Dirac representation between matter and anti-matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics, antimatter, representation-theory, matter

If $|\psi \rangle$ represents a wavefunction through a column matrix and $\langle \psi |$ represents the dual vector in a row matrix and $|\psi \rangle \langle \psi | = \rho $ is the probability density of the wavefunction collapse to a particular value in $\mathbb{R}$ by a measurement, and matter is also a wave (DeBroglie), how does one represent matter by using Dirac notations - how about anti-matter?  Would there be something similar to $\langle \psi |\psi \rangle  = n \in \mathbb{R} $ ?

I apologize if the question is quite ignorant, i.e. Dirac's equations don't relate matter/anti-matter, it just seems they should - and I would like to know how ;)

Thanks,

Brian

Comment: what do you think $| \psi \rangle$ represents physically?

Comment: @nervxxx, I thought it represented the wavefunction; a vector in a Complex Hilbert space which can be written by a column vector. That the inner product with its dual $\langle \psi |$ would give the probability $\langle \psi |\psi \rangle  = n \in \mathbb{R}$ (?) and the outer product $|\psi \rangle \langle \psi | = \rho$ (if outer product is the correct term for it), gives the probability density matrix.

Comment: I think it might be simmilar to the matter representation. Matter and antimatter are almost simmilar except for charges.